# Getting subprocess.Popen stdout when running by cron

Tags: linux, cron, python, stdout

I want to get a service status and if it's not up, to send the status (stdout) in email.
This script is scheduled to run every hour by cron.
When running manually, the following works fine:

```
def is_service_running(name):
with open(os.devnull, 'wb') as hide_output:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['service', name, 'status'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        output = proc.stdout.read()
        exit_code = proc.wait()
        return exit_code == 0, output
```

But when running by cron. `output` is empty.
How can I capture `stdout` when running by cron?
Thank you

Comment: Is it because /usr/sbin is in your interactive environment but not cron’s?

Comment: Hi @JeffSchaller, no idea.. that's why i'm asking :)

Comment: I think you should see if that popen call is successful. Maybe also use the full path to the service command.

Comment: @JeffSchaller You were close, see the answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't cron but `shell=True`.
Apparently, when using `shell=True`, popen expects single string and not a list.
So when I updated my call to:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['service ' + name + ' status'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

everything worked.